# Can't get Flask-socketIO to work on Raspberry Pi Zero

Tags: flask-socketio, raspberry-pi-zero

I'm trying to stream sensor (MPU9250) data from a Raspberry Pi, but I can't get Flask-socketIO to send data to the client. It serves the webpage, but nothing afterwards.
Here's the code - I've stripped out the sensor related code.

Once the page has initially loaded, I don't get any console.log messages, and the page seems to stop responding - e.g. if I click the refresh button, it just hangs. After some time I get a warning saying that 'WebSocket connection to..... failed: WebSocket is  closed before the connection is established"

I've been messing with this for the past few days to no avail. I've tried a tonne of things, but nothing has helped.

Any advice would be appreciated.

## MPU9250.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_socketio import SocketIO, emit
import smbus
import time

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'secret!'
async_mode = 'eventlet'
socketio = SocketIO(app, cors_allowed_origins="*", async_mode=async_mode)

### SENSOR CODE HERE

# Define a route for the HTML page
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

# Define a socketio event for streaming the MPU9250 data
@socketio.on('connect')
def stream():
    while True:
        # Read the acceleration and magnetometer data from MPU9250
        accel_xout = read_word_2c(accel_xout_h)
        accel_yout = read_word_2c(accel_yout_h)
        accel_zout = read_word_2c(accel_zout_h)
        mag_xout = read_word_2c(mag_xout_h)
        mag_yout = read_word_2c(mag_yout_h)
        mag_zout = read_word_2c(mag_zout_h)

        #Print outputs:
        print("X Accel: ", accel_xout, " | Y Accel: ", accel_yout, " | Z_Accel: ",     accel_zout)

        # Stream the acceleration and magnetometer data to the web page for plotting
        socketio.emit('acceleration', {'x': time.time(), 'y': accel_xout})
        socketio.emit('magnetometer', {'x': time.time(), 'y': mag_xout})
        socketio.send('Test message')
    
        time.sleep(0.1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    socketio.run(app, debug=True, port=80, host='0.0.0.0')
```

## index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>MPU9250 Sensor Data</title>
    <script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-bLT0Qm9VnAYZDflyKcBaQ2gg0hSYNQrJ8RilYldYQ1FxQYoCLtUjuuRuZo+fjqhx/qtq/1itJ0C2ejDxltZVFg==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/3.0.4/socket.io.js" integrity="sha512-aMGMvNYu8Ue4G+fHa359jcPb1u+ytAF+P2SCb+PxrjCdO3n3ZTxJ30zuH39rimUggmTwmh2u7wvQsDTHESnmfQ==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
      $(document).ready(function() {

          var socket = io();

          socket.on('connect', function() {
              socket.emit('my_event', {data: 'I\'m connected!'});
          });

          socket.on('my_response', function(msg, cb) {
              $('#log').append('<br>' + $('<div/>').text('Received #' + msg.count + ': '     + msg.data).html());
              if (cb)
                  cb();
          });

      });
  </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>MPU9250 Sensor Stream</h1>
    <h2>Acceleration</h2>
    <div id="acceleration-graph"></div>
    <h2>Magnetometer</h2>
    <div id="magnetometer-graph"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
      console.log("Here");

      const accelerationData = {
        x: [],
        y: [],
        mode: "lines",
        name: "Acceleration",
      };
      const magnetometerData = {
        x: [],
        y: [],
        mode: "lines",
        name: "Magnetometer",
      };

      const accelerationLayout = {
        title: "Acceleration Data",
        xaxis: { title: "Time" },
        yaxis: { title: "Acceleration (raw)" },
      };
      const magnetometerLayout = {
        title: "Magnetometer Data",
        xaxis: { title: "Time" },
        yaxis: { title: "Magnetic field (raw)" },
      };

      const accelerationPlot = Plotly.newPlot(
        "acceleration-graph",
        [accelerationData],
        accelerationLayout
      );
      const magnetometerPlot = Plotly.newPlot(
        "magnetometer-graph",
        [magnetometerData],
        magnetometerLayout
      );

      var socket = io();
      socket.on("connect", function () {
        socket.emit("my event", { data: "I'm connected!" });
      });

      socket.on("acceleration", function (data) {
        console.log('X_Accel: ' + accelerationData.x)
        accelerationData.x.push(data.x);
        accelerationData.y.push(data.y);
        Plotly.update(accelerationPlot, [accelerationData], accelerationLayout);
      });

      socket.on("magnetometer", function (data) {
        console.log('X_Mag: ' + magnetometerData.x)
        magnetometerData.x.push(data.x);
        magnetometerData.y.push(data.y);
        Plotly.update(magnetometerPlot, [magnetometerData], magnetometerLayout);
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please add server and client logs.

Comment: I managed to get the GitHub example working last night (it wasn't working at the time of posting my question) - so I'll explore a little more myself before taking up anyone else's time.